# .htaccess RewriteRule subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.tld to subdomain.domain.tld/subsubdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, dns, subdomain

Is it posible to redirect a sub-subdomain into a subdomain with the sub-sub domain as new folder using .htaccess rewrite-rule?

For example... When i go to 2013.archive.example.com I want to end up in archive.example.com/2013..

Already tried some things, current .htaccess is:

```
RewriteRule On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.archive\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ archive.example.com/%1/$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately it isn't working. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Do all the subdomains share the same document root?

Comment: There are some other subdomains... But url's like 2011.archive.example.com, 2012.archive.example.com, 2013.archive.. etc share the root of archive.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For external redirect: (URL change in browser)**

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.(archive\.example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%2/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This will work provided `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is same for `anything.archive.example.com` and `archive.example.com`.

**For internal forward: (No URL change in browser)**

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.archive\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: @anubhava The `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is `archive` or `example.com`?

Comment: That should be the directory where your `example.com` is pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

Changed it a but, currently using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.archive\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L]
```

and is working exactly how I wanted:)

Answer (score 0):

If they share the same root, then you don't need the `archive.example.com` part in your rule's target:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.archive\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```